# ncurses getyx(win, y, x) always returning '0,0'. Why?

Tags: c++, ncurses

EDIT 2:

as suspected the solution was hidden in plain sight. Thanks to @hyde for not only a helpful answer but one which taught me something i had not known before.

EDIT:

I had thought adding a little context would be helpful but perhaps it only has caused some misdirection. I'm sure the solution is simple and right under my nose.

I have a function:

```
cursorPosition(int y, int x)
{

getyx(_win, y, x);

}
```

i want this function to modify y and x to contain the cursor position of `_win`, a window object.

instead it returns y = 0, x = 0, persistently.

my question is what am i missing.

i will leave the rest of the post untouched. But you don't need to go further.

--*end transmission*--

i have a class object which uses the ncurses library and i am trying to get the position of the cursor in the screen.

I can clearly see that the cursor moves when i call `wmove` and `wprintw` methods within the window, but when i check the cursor position it reads y = 0, x = 0. I cannot figure out why it will not retrieve the actual cursor position. `getyx(stdscr,y,x )` and `getsyx(y,x)` seem to work fine which both use stdscr, but i need to use a new window and not the stdscr window.

here are some (relevant) details of my code:

I create class called `Window`.

Window is a wrapper for an ncurses window object, with methods to print to and modify that window:

```
class Window

{

public: 

// if int is 1: calls initscr and creates a newwin to assign to member variable 'win'
// if int is 0: calls delwin, sets member variable '_win' to nullptr then endwin
setWin(int)

// calls setWin(0) if member variable '_win' is not already nullptr
~Window()

// retrieves the cursor position 
cursorPosition(int y, int x)

private:

WINDOW * _win = nullptr;

}
```

HERE is the problem:

cursorPosition just wraps around '''getyx(_win,y,x)''', using the private member variable '''_win'''.
I will later create a shared pointer to this window object called `DISPLAY`, and i am doing this:

```
DISPLAY->setWin(1);

int CURSOR_Y, CURSOR_X;

DISPLAY->cursorPosition(CURSOR_Y, CURSOR_X);

std::string yx = std::tostring(CURSOR_Y) + "  " + std::to_string(CURSOR_X);

// prints to '_win' with 'wprintw'.
DISPLAY->print(yx)
```

however i always get back

"0 0"

And indeed this is true because when i try to use to navigate the window CURSOR_Y and CURSOR_X, anything i output is in the top left corner.

Comment: How could `cursorPosition` possibly modify its arguments?

Comment: I cannot see what you have done, your code is far from valid C++. Please read [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: i will not show you all 2000 lines of my code. instead i will just narrow it down to what i am asking see the edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getyx` etc are macros, and take internally the address of their y and x *macro* parameters. So you need to be able to modify the original `x` and `y` passed to your *function*.

Since you are using C++, simply use references:

```
cursorPosition(int &y, int &x)
```

Now when the macro internally takes address of `x` and `y`, it will get the address of the originals, not just local copies.

PS. This once again demonstrates how macros are quite horrible and create confusing code and confusing error messages (just try `getyx(_win, 1, 1);` to see).